# How to insert a spinner select items and current location "latitude" , "longitude" into MySQL db

Tags: php, android

I am working on a small Android PHP webservice application. I have 2 spinners cascading and when I click on the given button of the second one, it will be added to the base with the current position of the client (spot, latitude, longitude).

I can the data of the database spinner and the current location but I can not send it to the database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String MetierNamearray = "libelle_metier";
    public static final String MetierName  = "libelle_metier";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    private JSONArray result;
    Spinner spinner,spinner2;

    private GpsTracker gpsTracker;
    private TextView tvLatitude,tvLongitude;

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    TextView employeename;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrEmployee);
        spinner2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrTache);
        employeename= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), 
         android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
        {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 101);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        getMetiers();
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {
                //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
                employeename.setText(getemployeeName(position));


            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                employeename.setText("");

            }
        });
    }
    private void getMetiers() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new 
       StringRequest("http://192.168.1.234/getdata.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            j = new JSONObject(response);
                            result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                            empdetails(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void empdetails(JSONArray j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(json.getString(MetierNamearray));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // arrayList.add(0,"Select Employee");
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList));
    }
    //Method to get student name of a particular position
    private String getemployeeName(int position){
        String name="";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            //Fetching name from that object
            name = json.getString(MetierName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }

    public void getLocation(View view){
        gpsTracker = new GpsTracker(MainActivity.this);
        if(gpsTracker.canGetLocation()){
            double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
            tvLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
            tvLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));

        }else{
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }
}
```